# Is there a special meaning behind a hypothesis test that consistently report 0.5 as the p-value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

I have been conducting Likelihood Ratio Tests on Full and Reduced form linear models and there is a specific scenario where I consistently obtain p-values of 0.5. I am wondering if there was a special consequence of having a p-value of being exactly 0.5.

Comment: I agree with @jbowman that something must be wrong if tests with different data consistently show P-value exactly 0.5. // However, your question is so general that it gives no clue _what_ may be wrong. Specifically, please describe your 'specific scenario': what kind of data? what null hypothesis and what alternative? what test statistic? what criterion for rejection? // In many cases, under $H_0$ with a _continuous_ test statistic, the P-value is a random variable uniformly distributed on UNIF(0,1).

Comment: Please clarify the precise situation, if possible via a small reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you are using a special form of likelihood ratio test. Otherwise, no, a p-value of 0.5 does not have a special meaning.

It simply means there is 50% chance that the data in your sample are equally likely to be obtained from either underlying models.

Comment: Well, exactly 0.5 is unusual, and consistently exactly 0.5 is indicative of a mistake somewhere, it seems to me.